# Get current user data in ionic 2 from firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I develop an app with users in ionic 2 and firebase, the login and register are working, but when I want to get the current user the data is not working.

EDIT:

I have a concept error, I managed to get the email with this code:

```
this.usuarioEmail = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
```

EDIT 2:

I use this code for get the data related for these email:

```
this.usuario = af.database.list('/usuarios', {
     query: {
      orderByChild: 'Email',
      equalTo: this.usuarioEmail
    },
    preserveSnapshot: true });

   this.usuario.subscribe(snapshot => {
     snapshot.forEach(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.key)
        console.log(snapshot.child('Direccion').val())
        this.id = snapshot.key;
        this.direccion = snapshot.child('Direccion').val();

     });

   })
```

I found the answer, but i want know other metods.